# how using float css property rendering a span tag without any content inside it?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple HTML & CSS structure that I use for practice.

Please check the fiddle link attached.

I was working on a span tag and gave it some height & width but it was not rendering.

I know the reason. span is an inline tag and it does not respect height and width properties.

But suddenly I gave it a float property and it rendered on the page.

My question is how `float` property is affecting an inline element, even when it does not have any content inside.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

div.wrapper {
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

span.round{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background: orange;
  float:right; /** not using float, vanishes the whole span **/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="round"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing float to left / right has the side effect of changing the display property to block. Similar effect if position is made absolute.

Comment: @SalmanA was going to remove it also :p .. bad copy/past of the wrong quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from Mozilla Developer section:
"As float implies the use of the block layout, it modifies the computed value of the display values".
As of the result, the  tag will be automatically block type.